# Не могу получить список активных задач Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

Пытаюсь получить список активных задач Celery

```
from celery.app.control import Inspect

...

i = Inspect()
i.active()

...
```

Выходит такая ошибка

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'control'
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как исправить эту ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы добавляли `celery` в ваш проект по [офф. документации](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) то можете открыть консоль через

```
python manage.py shell
```

и сделать импорт вашего `celery` приложения

```
from your_project import celery_app
```

Затем можете выполнить

```
i = celery_app.control.inspect()
i.active()
```

Comment: А как это прописать во вьюхе?

Comment: всё так же, только не нужно в `shell` заходить

Comment: возможно вам `flower` подойдет, что бы свои вьюхи для `celery` не городить

Comment: уфф, кое как разобрался, from your_project import celery_app - вот эту строчку pycharm почему-то красным подчеркивает, нооо при этом всё работает

Comment: `your_project ` тут имелось ввиду название конкретно вашего проекта) но если вы меня поняли и сделали всё верно но pycharm всё равно ругается - попробуйте зайти в настройки, там выбрать структуру проекта и пометить папку с кодом как `Source`

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог то вы можете отметить его как правильный